Проблема с отладкой в JetBrains Rider
Прошу прощения заранее, за может глупый вопрос, у меня проблема в том, что при дебаге проекта открываются, как я понимаю вспомогательные файлы, как отключить это или пропустить? Пробелма в том, что при каждом шаге, вместо того чтобы дебажить мой проект, я прохожусь по доступной документации, что очень мешает

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Enable external source debug в поисках по настройкам.
